# Extracting data from an input file using SORT to different output files not providing expected data

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I am using SORT to process an input file and extract records that match three different criteria.  The criteria is laid out in the control statements.  I am looking for fields that match the text `GROUND OPERATIONS`, `TECHNICAL OPERATI` and `AIRPORT TRANSFERS`.  I want records from the input that match each of the conditions to be written to a corresponding output file.  The DDs for the output file are `SORTOF01`, `SORTOF02` and `SORTOF03` respectively.

I can see there are records that match my criteria in the input file but when executed the SORT completes but no records are selected.  I’m missing something but I don’t know what it is.  The JCL and control statements for the SORT are supplied below.

```
//PROB3   EXEC PGM=SORT                                      
//SORTIN  DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLNON,DISP=SHR
//SORTOF01 DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLN01,       
//           DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                        
//           LIKE=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLNON        
//SORTOF02 DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLN02,       
//           DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                        
//           LIKE=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLNON        
//SORTOF03 DD DSN=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLN03,       
//           DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                        
//           LIKE=XXX.T.KR0Z1N99.RU02.FTPGEN.THOTLNON        
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSIN    DD *                                              
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                           
  INCLUDE COND=(93,3,CH,EQ,C'YES')                           
  OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(73,20,CH,EQ,C'GROUND OPERATIONS') 
  OUTFIL FILES=02,INCLUDE=(73,20,CH,EQ,C'TECHNICAL OPERATI') 
  OUTFIL FILES=03,INCLUDE=(73,20,CH,EQ,C'AIRPORT TRANSFERS')
```

Comment: Once again - this is not a JCL question so remove that tag. Putting JCL and SORT together as you have is senseless unless you are trying to sort some JCL or you require the JCL to execute the sort program. Whether it is a batch job or some other method of invocation the control statements are going to be the same. Which data set (not file) was empty? Maybe there were no records for that file. To put records into any of those data sets they must have YES in cols 93-95 and the relevant text in columns 73 to 92. And note that the strings that you are searching for are 17 bytes long not 20.

Comment: Try using a length of17, What is the data file you are copying, is it VB and have you adjusted the columns for that ??

Comment: Thanks martin for the response..its worked for me

Comment: @BruceMartin It would be good for you to provide your answer below.  I edited the question to reflect @maheshKumar’s intent.  Your answer is helpful.  Hopefully Mahesh will respond and accept your answer

Comment: Hogstrom it should be @NicC who answers; I will add an answer, Nic if you want to answer, I can delete my answer

Comment: @BruceMartin. Yup yup ... thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I only revisited yesterday. Not bothered if it stays as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the **length** from `20` to `17` as below

```
//SYSIN    DD *                                              
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                           
  INCLUDE COND=(93,3,CH,EQ,C'YES')                           
  OUTFIL FILES=01,INCLUDE=(73,17,CH,EQ,C'GROUND OPERATIONS') 
  OUTFIL FILES=02,INCLUDE=(73,17,CH,EQ,C'TECHNICAL OPERATI') 
  OUTFIL FILES=03,INCLUDE=(73,17,CH,EQ,C'AIRPORT TRANSFERS')
```

Comparing 20 bytes with 17 bytes is probably going to be false

---

When having problems with sort, **Always check the Record-Format**, if the `RECFM` is **VB** you need to `add 4` to all positions